# how to delete a file from a directory before download

Tags: javascript, php, file, download

```
saveJPGButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {

  alert("Please provide a signature first.");
} else {

    var dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    download(dataURL, "signature.jpg");
} });
```

hi, this is the code that allows me to download an image after clicking on a specific button. before the image is downloaded, I need to delete, in the same folder, the file that has the same name as the file that I will have downloaded. how can I do?

Comment: You can call an ajax action with name of file and delete it with php.

Comment: You can't delete files on the user's computer

Comment: If you are talking about deleting the same file from the server and then create the same file on the server, then there is no need to do anything. The new file (with the same filename) will overwrite the existing one. If you are talking about deleting the file on your local machine before you download, I think it is NOT possible because a browser triggered action will not have the permission to delete any files in your download folder , otherwise it is a serious security threat.